# Raspberry pi 3b+ with Python wifi library

Tags: python

Please has anyone has any luck using the python wifi library in a python script to setup wifi on the raspberry pi 3b+?

I have been trying for a long time now, but no luck. I have configured wifi country and other necessary settings but no luck configuring the wifi.

https://wifi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Please, can you comment if you have done this on the raspberry pi 3b+ exactly or if you have had any problems with this python module in general. Here is the link:

[python wifi library](https://wifi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Comment: Could you show us what you've tried?

Comment: Okay, there is an examplet that is provided on the doc page. https://wifi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/scanning.html . It works relatively well on the raspberry pi 3. But I have put in weeks, still no much success. Have you had any similar problems?

Comment: I've never tried it. But I've followed the link you sent. It doesn't seem to be an example so much as some Python commands entered in the shell. Which one of these commands doesn't work, and what is the error you're getting?

Comment: `cell = Cell.all('wlan0')[0]                                                                                scheme = Scheme.for_cell('wlan0', 'home', cell, passkey)
scheme.save()
scheme.activate()`

Comment: I basically takes a username and password and tries to connect to the wifi

Comment: How did you install the Python wifi library? Which version of Python are you using?

Comment: The project you are linked to is unmaintained. You are using a Raspberry Pi 3B+ that is fairly new and has a new wifi chip on board supporting the 5GHz band. Maybe this is a problem.

Comment: And what do you get for `cell`? i.e. what does `print(cell)` show?

Comment: @Ingo: Suspect you're correct, but I do get a return value from `Cell.all('wlan0')`. But it's a `map object` instead of a list. [Apparently the `map` function in Python 3 works differently than in Python 2.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40015439/why-does-map-return-a-map-object-instead-of-a-list-in-python-3)

Comment: Okay, I am using python3. I suspected its because the module is not maintained. Its there any python wifi module that is maintained? I am working on a project that requires the user to setup up his wifi on first boot up.

Comment: I've tried two different Python wifi libraries; neither of them seem to work, and neither appear to be "active/maintained" projects: [python-wifi 0.6.1](https://pypi.org/project/python-wifi/), and [wifi](https://github.com/rockymeza/wifi). The latter is the one you've been using I believe. I'm afraid I have nothing else I can offer except to suggest you try the [Stack Overflow forum](https://stackoverflow.com/), or possibly Google "python wifi library".